# Issue with tablayout, on switching to the second tab it will jump back to the first tab

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am trying to create a tab layout for my program.
There are two tabs. If I try to switch to Tab2 instead of staying on Tab2, it changes back to Tab1. I have 0 clue what is causing this problem.

Here is my code

MainActivity:

```
tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentAdapter = new CustomAdapter(fragmentManager, getLifecycle());

    viewPager2.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });

    viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(state));
        }
    });
```

CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

public CustomAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
    super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    if(position == 1) return new BlankFragment1();
    return new BlankFragment2();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2) you can use a `TabLayoutMediator` to link the tab layout and pager instead of doing it with your own listeners.

However, the root of the problem you observed is that `state` in [`onPageScrollStateChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback#onPageScrollStateChanged(int)) is not the position that it scrolled to - it is an integer representing the scroll state. Since `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` is 0, and `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING` is 1, as soon as you stopped dragging it would snap back to tab 0.

**Using TabLayoutMediator (recommended)**

To use the TabLayoutMediator replace your `addOnTabSelectedListener`, `registerOnPageChangeCallback`, and manually setting the tabs (`addTab`) with this, which links the tabs to the view pager and provides a method to set the tab titles

```java
// remove the "addTab" calls, "addOnTabSelectedListener", 
// and "registerOnPageChangeCallback"

new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2,
        (tab, position) -> tab.setText("Tab" + (position + 1))
).attach();
```

**Using your own listeners**

It is still possible to use your own listeners, but you have to change the view pager listener to use `onPageSelected` instead of `onPageScrollStateChanged`, like this:

```java
viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
    }
});
```

*Note*: The positions are 0-based, so you are showing "BlankFragment2" in position 0 and "BlankFragment1" in position 1 (not sure if that is what you intended).